# Z3 significance of Z3_get_ast_id

Tags: z3

I want to know the semantics of Z3_get_ast_id(). When will two expressions have same id? If two expressions are created using same context using same arguments and opcodes, will the id be same?

I also see that there is Z3_get_ast_hash(). Please tell the semantics of this function too.

Answer (score 1):

```
    The identifier is unique up to structural equality. Thus, two ast nodes
    created by the same context and having the same children and same function symbols
    have the same identifiers. Ast nodes created in the same context, but having
    different children or different functions have different identifiers.
    Variables and quantifiers are also assigned different identifiers according to
    their structure.
```

You can use Z3_get_ast_id interchangeably with Z3_get_ast_hash